# Call to a member function execute() on boolean

Tags: php, json, phpmyadmin

Есть пхп файл, отобращающий БД в формате JSON.
 PHP:

```
<?php 

 //database constants
 define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
 define('DB_USER', 'binskiy');
 define('DB_PASS', 'binskiy2018');
 define('DB_NAME', 'binskiydb');

 //connecting to database and getting the connection object
 $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

 //Checking if any error occured while connecting
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 die();
 }

 //creating a query
 $stmt = $conn->prepare ("SELECT accommodation_conditions, address, cancellation_or_prepayment, cards, desc, features, general, imageurl, infrastructure, latitude, link, location, longitude, name, notes, pets, price, services, sport_and_leisure, stars, tourist_taxi, type, with_kids FROM hotels;");

 //executing the query 
 $stmt->execute();

 //binding results to the query 
 $stmt->bind_result($accommodation_conditions, $address, $cancellation_or_prepayment, $cards, $desc, $features, $general, $imageurl, $infrastructure, $latitude, $link, $location, $longitude, $name, $notes, $pets, $price, $services, $sport_and_leisure, $stars, $tourist_tax, $type, $with_kids);

 $hotels = array(); 

 //traversing through all the result 
 while($stmt->fetch()){
 $temp = array();
 $temp['accommodation_conditions'] = $accommodation_conditions;
 $temp['address'] = $address;
 $temp['cancellation_or_prepayment'] = $cancellation_or_prepayment;
 $temp['cards'] = $cards;
 $temp['desc'] = $desc;
 $temp['features'] = $features;
 $temp['general'] = $general;
 $temp['imageurl'] = $imageurl;
 $temp['infrastructure'] = $infrastructure;
 $temp['latitude'] = $latitude;
 $temp['link'] = $link;
 $temp['location'] = $location;
 $temp['longitude'] = $longitude;
 $temp['name'] = $name;
 $temp['notes'] = $notes;
 $temp['pets'] = $pets;
 $temp['price'] = $price;
 $temp['services'] = $services;
 $temp['sport_and_leisure'] = $sport_and_leisure;
 $temp['stars'] = $stars;
 $temp['tourist_tax'] = $tourist_tax;
 $temp['type'] = $type;
 $temp['with_kids'] = $with_kids;
 array_push($hotels, $temp);
 }

 //displaying the result in json format 
 echo json_encode($hotels);
```

Постоянно при запуске файла выбивает ошибку:

> **Fatal error**: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\omk\binskiy\get_hotels.php on line 22

В этой строке:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: по всей видимости у вас SQL запрос не корректен, проверьте поля

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$conn->prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) может вернуть `FALSE`. Нужно проверять, с ошибкой ли отработал  `prepare` или нет.

```
if($stmt = $conn->prepare ("SELECT accommodation_conditions, address, cancellation_or_prepayment, cards, desc, features, general, imageurl, infrastructure, latitude, link, location, longitude, name, notes, pets, price, services, sport_and_leisure, stars, tourist_taxi, type, with_kids FROM hotels;")) {
    // тут остальной код, если всё ок
}
```

Конкретно у вас ошибка в том, что запрос оканчивается на `;`. Не нужно этого. В доках же всё указано:

> Note:
>
> You should not add a terminating semicolon or \g to the statement.